# Making MDF look like plywood with layered edges

Tags: plywood, mdf, veneer, edge-banding

I'm wanting to make a cheap birch ply-looking worktop for myself with MDF.

The only issue I have is that I would also like to have the layered plywood edge rather than a traditional edge banding.

The actual top face of the worktop would be relatively simple as I have seen some [sticky-back vinyl](https://www.vinylwarehouse.co.uk/90cm-birch-wood-sticky-back-vinyl-200-5475-lengths-from-1m-to-15m-7222-p.asp) online at a reasonable cost, however I have not come across anything similar for a simulated plywood edge...

Is this something that actually exists? I understand that typically, edging is done to cover up the layered edge... So I might just be being awkward here.

Comment: I have plywood edge look-alike edge banding on the drawers of a particle board dresser, so it definitely exists. I have no idea where it came from, though.

Comment: Don't suppose I could steal your drawers? XD

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer MDF over plywood here beyond cost? Shopping around might yield a plywood option that's good enough for what you need, and price-competitive with MDF, especially with the saving of the cost of the vinyl and edge banding factored in. With the scarcity/unavailability of 'Baltic birch' ply, or its greatly inflated prices, there are numerous things online from the past year or two about potential replacements.

Comment: We’re not supposed to link products, but what you want exists — it’s just a matter of finding a reasonable quantity. https://www.woodworkerexpress.com/edgebanding-pvc-3d001r-multiplex-beech-15-16-x-2mm-lf-roll-woodtape-3d001r-1402-29.html

Comment: Fair enough for not linking products; just knowing what to search for would be a start :-P I think I did manage to find a UK-based product similar to what you showed, but they have completely generic 'edge banding' names to my annoyance!

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, linking to products is actually fine, many many prior Answers here link to specific product pages for finish, hardware, router bits etc. (and it's done all the time across the whole site). It's *asking* for specific products that is against the rules.

Comment: @physicsboy, using AloysiusDefenestrate's link above as a starting point I just tried a search for "multiplex birch" and Google suggested an autocomplete of "multiplex birch edge banding" so it's most definitely a thing! And it is available over here. I'm presuming you'd be buying the MDF locally, so no delivery charge there, but once P&P gets added to the cost of the banding and vinyl you're at least a lot of the way towards the price of a decent plywood, possibly over it.